# segue between navigation controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have 2 navigation controllers. I want to perform segue from one to another and change  navigation stack. I'm using SWRevealViewController library for my hamburger menu. When I perform segue as on picture, menu does't work. How can I perform segue correctly? (Sorry for my english) I couldn't find any post like this. I am using swift language.

here is my storyboard
https://yadi.sk/d/z_biSNaejRoGJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerID") as? ViewController {
                                    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController)
                                    navController.setViewControllers([secondViewController], animated:true)
                                    self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(navController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a manuel segue from your first view controller to another. There is not a trigger(button etc.) to the initiate your segue. You have to initiate your segue with code. You can use this code for initiate your segue;

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("authComplete", sender: nil)
```

If you put this code with your any @IBAction it should be initiate your segue. Have a nice coding.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I meant to change rootViewController in fact)